# count if element contains certain text and print the result on page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm doing something weird here, pleae assist if you may.
I have a webpage with a report which looks like this:

```
</p></li><li>ARTICLE 1 (NAME 1)<br /><p>    
<div class="list">
Nothing found. 
</div>
</p></li><li>ARTICLE 2 (NAME 2)<br /><p>    

<div class="list">
<h4 class="sub-heading">Items:</h4>  
<li class="item">
...
</li>
<li class="item">
...
</li>

</div>
```

This repeats throughout the page. Article X is always unique, while Name X may be the same near several Articles. The p elements are inserted by me and can be changed (while css cannot). The divs are output of a plugin beyond my reach. The plugin searches some db and returns "nothing found" or lists the found items.
There should be a table on the same page where all the possible Name X are listed and have 0 across each name by default. What I want to achieve is count Name X and increase the counter near the name only if "nothing found" exists in the element following the p with the Article. I.e, in the above example the table should read

```
 Name 1     1

 Name 2     0
```

The same Name X may be found later in the page after next ARTICLE X and with or without "nothing found" in the next element. The rule to increase the counter only if "nothing found" exists should apply.
My first idea was to hide all elements and leave only the list of ARTICLE X where "nothing found" exists in the element below. I did that, and then used the following code to count:

```
  var n = $("li:contains('Name 1')").length;
  $("span").text("There are " + n)
```

This is wrong on so many levels. First, it reads the source code which still contains all the elements as even they are hidden they still exist. It also obviously replaces text in all span elements which do exist on page (I've taken the span from .text description), and I don't really know how to insert the output given I can't control page layout.
Any ideas highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do here

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying my best to explain. The basic idea is to create a table that counts lines containing "NAME 1" but only if the next line contains "Nothing found" and put the result as a digit on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a count by first selecting elements containing `NAME 1`, and then checking if they have a child element which contains `Nothing found`, eg.

```
$('li:contains("NAME 1")').children('.list:contains("Nothing found")').length;
```

For creating and injecting elements into the DOM, have a look at the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements)

You can also have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2a5b/8), which is a really basic example of what I think you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. Is .length supposed to output something without additional code? It's not exactly clear from the description.

Comment: @EasyLife That's just the selector for getting the number of elements, I've put a basic demo together here: http://jsfiddle.net/u2a5b/8/

Comment: OMG it works! I did some editing since the Names are real people who are not royal enough to have numbers in their names.:)) but it counts! The magic of this site users is amazing. I still have to find a way to insert formatting on the table, but it works. Thank you so much and have a beautiful day.

Comment: could I bother you just a little more? I can't figure out how can I include ( after contains(" so that it wouldn't be treated as markup.

Comment: In the examples above it is not NAME 1 but (NAME 1). If I enter it as li:contains("(NAME 1)") the code fails to perform. Is there a way to transcode or something the ( and ) so it could be used?

Comment: Should work fine, you sure you don't have any spaces etc? [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/3vrtA/1/)

Comment: Hm... it does for  li:contains("(NAME 1)")  but does not for li:contains("(NAME")   . Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, try this snippet:

```
var counter = 0;

$('li').each(function(){
     if($(this).html().indexOf('Name 1')> -1)
         if($(this).next('div.list').html() === "Nothing found.")
             {++counter}
});
```